# UnsatisfiedDependencyException with springboot

Tags: java, spring

I'm with difficulties on SpringBoot. I'm following a course class, my code it's exactly equals of my professor but my code give me this error(I've tried to fix this with many solutions like creating a bean in another .xml, annoting in the main class with @EntityScan and @ComponentScan, nothing worked for me):

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.4.RELEASE)

2020-02-22 21:15:17.728  INFO 8108 --- [           main] br.com.luis.restwithspringboot.Main      : Starting Main on DESKTOP-HVESQU8 with PID 8108 (started by lucar in C:\Users\lucar\IdeaProjects\RestWithSpringBootUdemy\02 RestWithSpringBootInitialzr)
2020-02-22 21:15:17.731  INFO 8108 --- [           main] br.com.luis.restwithspringboot.Main      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-02-22 21:15:18.842  INFO 8108 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-02-22 21:15:18.850  INFO 8108 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-02-22 21:15:18.851  INFO 8108 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.30]
2020-02-22 21:15:18.951  INFO 8108 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-02-22 21:15:18.952  INFO 8108 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1178 ms
2020-02-22 21:15:18.992  WARN 8108 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'personController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'service'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'personService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'br.com.luis.restwithspringboot.repository.PersonRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2020-02-22 21:15:18.994  INFO 8108 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-02-22 21:15:19.083  INFO 8108 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-02-22 21:15:19.174 ERROR 8108 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field repository in br.com.luis.restwithspringboot.services.PersonService required a bean of type 'br.com.luis.restwithspringboot.repository.PersonRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'br.com.luis.restwithspringboot.repository.PersonRepository' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

My Main class:

```
package br.com.luis.restwithspringboot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({ "br.com.luis.restwithspringboot.*" })
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }

}
```

My PersonRepository class:

```
package br.com.luis.restwithspringboot.repository;

import br.com.luis.restwithspringboot.model.Person;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {

}
```

My PersonService class:

```
package br.com.luis.restwithspringboot.services;

import br.com.luis.restwithspringboot.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundException;
import br.com.luis.restwithspringboot.model.Person;
import br.com.luis.restwithspringboot.repository.PersonRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class PersonService {

    @Autowired
    PersonRepository repository;

    public Person create(Person person) {
        return repository.save(person);
    }

    public List<Person> findAll() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    public Person findById(Long id) {

        return repository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("No records found for this ID"));
    }

    public Person update(Person person) {
        Person entity = repository.findById(person.getId())
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("No records found for this ID"));

        entity.setFirstName(person.getFirstName());
        entity.setLastName(person.getLastName());
        entity.setAddress(person.getAddress());
        entity.setGender(person.getGender());

        return repository.save(entity);
    }

    public void delete(Long id) {
        Person entity = repository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("No records found for this ID"));
        repository.delete(entity);
    }

}
```

My PersonController class:

```
package br.com.luis.restwithspringboot.controllers;

import br.com.luis.restwithspringboot.model.Person;
import br.com.luis.restwithspringboot.services.PersonService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/person")
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    private PersonService service;

    @GetMapping
    public List<Person> findAll() {
        return service.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Person findById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        return service.findById(id);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Person create(@RequestBody Person person) {
        return service.create(person);
    }

    @PutMapping
    public Person update(@RequestBody Person person) {
        return service.update(person);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> delete(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        service.delete(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
}
```

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>br.com.luis</groupId>
    <artifactId>restwithspringboot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>restwithspringboot</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

All of the pom.xml was generated by Spring Initializr of the Intellij IDEA. I hope anyone may help me. Thanks guys! If you need any other code just say to me, I'll send immediately.

Edit:

With @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "br.luis.restwithspringboot.*"):

```
      .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.4.RELEASE)

2020-02-22 21:58:00.228  INFO 6888 --- [           main] br.com.luis.restwithspringboot.Main      : Starting Main on DESKTOP-HVESQU8 with PID 6888 (started by lucar in C:\Users\lucar\IdeaProjects\RestWithSpringBootUdemy\02 RestWithSpringBootInitialzr)
2020-02-22 21:58:00.232  INFO 6888 --- [           main] br.com.luis.restwithspringboot.Main      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-02-22 21:58:00.791 ERROR 6888 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigExtension.<clinit>(JpaRepositoryConfigExtension.java:76) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.getExtension(JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.java:46) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.registerBeanDefinitions(RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.java:101) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.lambda$loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars$1(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:385) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:384) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:148) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at br.com.luis.restwithspringboot.Main.main(Main.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

Solved: Added @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "my.package.*") in the Main class above or below @SpringBootApplication and adding the dependency on pom.xml like Jacob and Hussain said, thanks guys!

Comment: It looks like you're missing `@EnableJpaRepositories`

Comment: @JacobG. @EnableJpaRepositores(basePackages = "my package here") right? I've edited my post with the exception

Comment: You'll also need to depend on `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` in your `pom.xml`

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I've been looking for this for 4 hours, just a last question, my GET request give me and exception "Invalid column name", but I've already changed the column name to the right name and keep coming this exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above exception/error is thrown because java class loader unable to find the class "PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" which is available under the artifact "spring-orm".

Issue should get resolved by adding below dependency

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

After adding above dependency it may fail with "Failed to configure a DataSource" because there are no database configurations defined in your project. You can use embedded database by adding below dependency. Below H2 dependency brings up in-memory database.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
   <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you, actually I'm using SQL Server, but it's giving me "Invalid Column name", but in every place I just copy paste the name exactly how its write on the database, any ideas of the error?

Comment: can you share me your model class?

Comment: my application.properties looks like below


spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

Comment: For hibernate5 I solved this issue by puting next lines in my application.properties file
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

else it maps firstName to first_name by default.